# Stop DB Project Launching by default when hit F5.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dbproj

Using: MVC3, Vs2010, and a DbProject

In a Solution I have an MVC3 project and a DB project. Whenever I hit f5 to startup the MVC project, the DBproject starts before. I dont want this behavior. I just want to launch the MVC project and not both projects.

The MVC project its set up as start up project.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Right click on solution and see Build ORder/Project dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the solution and select configuration manager. Then uncheck the DB Project for the build configurations you need.